# Event view in Calendar app

Tags: calendar, view

I have used 2 web parts different views of same app(calendar) in single page.

One web part having calendar app(calendar view) and another having Calendar app(events list view).

I want to display events list as per we select month in first web part i.e. events should be displayed month wise(not whole event list).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: JavaScript helps you,get a date on click event from the date you should find month of selected date and On that particular month get event list in one page(HTML) and by the content editor web part it page display in another web part

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this with the help of [SharePoint events calendar add-in](http://365appz.ngenioussolutions.com/sharepoint-events-calendar-add-in.html). You can make display event updates as per category wise in calendar format.